# Data Store error when registering a database in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, postgresql

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1 and have downloaded the PostgreSQL 9.3.5 files from MyESRI.com. PostgreSQL is installed locally for testing purposes. I have everything working smoothly and am attempting to publish the data for use on a tablet in the Esri Collector app. In order to do this I have to register the database with ArcGIS Server.

I edited the pg_hba.conf to allow remote connections, since ArcServer is installed on another machine. When I attempt to register the database I get he error in the following screenshot. I have attempted an exhaustive Google sreach for a resolution with no success.

[image]

Comment: Not an expert on postgresql but if arcgis server is on a different server than the database shouldn't your connection string have SERVER set to the DB server name and not localhost?

Comment: It looks like you used an incorrect option for registration. ArcGIS Data Store is a PostgreSQL instance, but one that is managed from ArcObjects (not something you would install yourself)